# UI Calendar with Events not working ONLY in ie 8 and lower

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, events, calendar

I have this code on pastebin, it's a bit long code because of the switches but the main point is: when I click next on calendar, it sets a variable, appends the cached content and hide all others on a switch with the variable. ( This isn't happening only on IE8 lower - it doesn't update the content on the right, only change calendar month. )

It works nice in every updated major browser but I really need it to works on IE 8 too but I just can't see what is doing this bug and since I use IETester I can't debug it for myself.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/aA5Scfpb

I would be very pleased if anyone could help me.
Thanks in advance,
Pedro Henrique

Edit: Sorry forgot to add the link to see it in action - http://www.ccbeuc.com.br/index.php/site/calendario

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it on IE8 and IE7 and it's fine. Are you sure Javascript is turned on? We are talking about the calendar on the left side, right?

**Edit:**

Are you sure it's not just IETester?!

Comment: Hmmmm... I don't think it's only on IETester...

Yes we are talking about the Calendar on the Left Side but when 'clicks' to next month it should update the right content with events of the next month.

In IE8 it does not update the content but Major Updated Browsers do.

I'm actually pretty sure that it is something with my JS code. But I can't find where and can't debug it right...

What I know is, when the page is loaded everything works fine. When the 'Calendar Next/Prev Button' is clicked (same function from load is called), it does not work (update content).

Answer (score 0):

Done.

I was wrong trying to attach an event to any button of the calendar.
I went throught jQuery UI Manual and found an event called onChangeMonthYear.

I corrected everything and build a new function. It works!

Here is the final code: http://pastebin.com/skv53tge

Thanks all for help.